# Django two models with ForeginKey but one of it is not defined

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models and every have ForeginKey to other and I have problem when server try run it because on of it don't see other because only one is defined.

It's any possible to have this and run server without errors?

**Model.py:**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, blank=True, null=True)
    deadline_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
    finished_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False)
    (...)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    (...)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`lazy relationships`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).
In your `Comment` model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey('Task', on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    ....
```

And in `Task`:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey('Comment', blank=True, null=True)
    .....
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the alternative syntax when you pass model classes as strings.

```
somestuff = models.ForeignKey("myapp.SomeStuff", ...)
```

So in your case all you need to do is add a pair of "

```
comment = models.ForeignKey("Comment", blank=True, null=True)
```